# "RuntimeException: Unable to start activity" при попытке создать Activity

Tags: java, android

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static class Account{
        String acc;
        int price;
        Account(String acc, int price){
            this.acc = acc;
            this.price = price;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText acc_add = findViewById(R.id.acc_edit);
        final EditText price_add = findViewById(R.id.price_edit);
        final Button add_btn =  findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
        final ListView acc_list = findViewById(R.id.list_add);

        final AccAdapter adapter = new AccAdapter();
        acc_list.setAdapter(adapter);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference();

        add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.add(new Account(acc_add.getText().toString(), Integer.valueOf(price_add.getText().toString())));
            }
        });


    private class AccAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Account> {
        AccAdapter(){ super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.acc); }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
           final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.acc, null);
           final Account account = getItem(position);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(account.acc);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).setText(String.valueOf(account.price));
            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

Ошибка как то связана с `acc_list.setAdapter(adapter);`

**Сама ошибка:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.psnaccounts, PID: 17048
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.psnaccounts/com.example.psnaccounts.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3308)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.psnaccounts.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3283)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
I/ple.psnaccount: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=679 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
```

Comment: приложите пожалуйста код разметки активности, возможно у вас отсутствует list_add в xml

Comment: Приложите пожалуйста шаблон активити

Comment: Получилось что?

Comment: Эмм как бы сказать нет, я так и не смог получить id списка->который находится в фрагменте(в активити хотел получить) поэтому забил на фрагменты и все сделал в MainActivity

Comment: @SmileXD, спрашивайте если что. С фрагментами вам рано или поздно все равно, скорее всего, придется разбираться.

Comment: Спасибо за все но мучает один вопрос, вот вы представили мне пример как я с фрагмента могу обратиться к активити,а мне нужно наоборот

Comment: У меня весь код находиться в Activity, единственное что я не могу сделать обратить к Listview и кнопке во фрагменте

Comment: @SmileXD, в следующий раз или вставляйте упоминание через `@МихаилРебров`, либо под ответом моим комментарий оставляйте, чтобы мне уведомление пришло. Чудом Ваш коммент заметил.

Comment: @SmileXD, "нужно" и "хочется" - это разные вещи. Весь код в активити - не самая лучшая идея. Выполнять те или иные действия нужно там где это и задуманно. И для инициализации компонентов используемых в фрагменте есть метод `onViewCreated()`. Во всяком случае так предполагает архитектура Android. Которая может предписывать то что и где нужно делать и наоборот ограничивать область ваших действий.

Comment: @SmileXD, какие у вас сложности с последним кейсом возникают(инициализация списка во фрагменте)? Дальше будет больше... (я про разделение кода)

Comment: скажу так мне нужно засунуть список допустим в переменную List и использовать ее в Активити.

Comment: @SmileXD ну так засовывайте  в переменную в Активистки, а вью инициализируйте во фрагменте. Я про разделение данных и отображения

Comment: @МихаилРебров спасибо за помощь! казалось все должно быть очень легко и я не должен стараться, но со временем я больше начинаю разбираться во всем этом надеюсь после некоторого времени когда начну изучать подробнее фрагменты вернусь к вашему решению.

Comment: Удачи вам, пишите если что

Comment: @МихаилРебров Здраствуйте! Можете помочь с проблемой? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1334122

Comment: @SmileXD, я в дороге. Приеду только ночью, а освобожусь и того позже. Как освобожусь - посмотрю

Comment: @МихаилРебров спасибо большое буду ждать))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ошибке сказано:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'void
> android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
> null object reference

Другими словами Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `setAdapter()` на переменной равной null.

Эта переменная,как вы уже сами догадались - `acc_list`.
А равна null, она потому что Вы не смогли найти её в контексте приложения.

```java
final ListView acc_list = findViewById(R.id.list_add);
```

Это значит, что списка с таким Id нет в layout'е данного активити.

Добавьте в разметку вашего активити:

```xml
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_add"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

---

### UPDATE

#### Касательно фрагмента

**В чем заключается проблема?**
Проблема в том, что Вы запускаете Ваш код до того как фрагмент был создан и не можете видеть список, который находится внутри него.

**Почему так происходит?**
Вы разместили Ваш код в методе `MainActivity.onCreate()`.
Данный метод вызывается до того, как фрагмент был создан.

Ниже я разместил наиболее полную схему жизненного цикла активити и фрагмента.

[image: Жизненный цикл]

**Что делать?**
Для доступа и инициализации списка лучше переопределить метод `onCreateView()` **в Вашем фрагменте**(не в активити) и уже в нем получать Ваш список и навешивать колбеки на зависящие от него объекты.
Объекты, которых нет во фрагменте можно получить через активити.

В примере, расположенном ниже, я предположил что список находится во фрагменте, а остальные элементы непосредственно в шаблоне активити

- поэтому список я получаю с помощью:

```
(ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list_add)
```

- а все остальные через активити

```
(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.add_btn)
```

Если другие объекты расположены также во фрагменте, просто используйте первый метод(через View фрагмента) для их нахождения.

**Пример onCreateView**

```java
// реализация фрагмента схематическая
// надеюсь получится самостоятельно адаптировать его в своих целях

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_identifier, container, false);
  // ...

  // получаем текущее активити и ищем в нем View кнопок и прочих элементов
   final Button add_btn =  (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.add_btn);

  // получаем View фрагмента и ищем в нем View списка
  final ListView acc_list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list_add);

  // ...

  // устанавливаем обработчик события клика на кнопку
  add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // ...
    }
  });
  /// ...
  return view;
}
```

Надеюсь это Вам поможет.
Если нет, то прикладывайте шаблоны и код фрагмента.

Comment: а как я могу обратиться к list_add который находится у меня в фрагменте?

Comment: У вас время есть помочь на счет фрагментов?

Comment: Я надеюсь вы освободились)) а то я никак не разберусь

Comment: Хорошо спасибо большое извините за беспокойство и берегите себя

Comment: Спасибо большое