# Как передать значение Listview в другое Activity при клике на значение из списка?(Значения Listview берется из FireBase)

Tags: java, android, firebase

Когда я передаю этим образом передается только 1 Значение из списка и его свойства

**Listview берет свой дизайн из другого XML**

```
    list.setClickable(true);
    //Передача в новое Активити
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            Intent about = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
            TextView name1 = findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView about1 = findViewById(R.id.about);
            TextView price1 = findViewById(R.id.price);
            String pack = name1.getText().toString();
            String about_text = about1.getText().toString();
            String price_text = price1.getText().toString();
            about.putExtra("packname", pack);
            about.putExtra("about_text", about_text);
            about.putExtra("price_text", price_text);
            startActivity(about);
            
        }
    });


      //Адаптер для ListView
private class AccAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Accounts> {
    AccAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_design);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_design, null);
        final Accounts accounts = getItem(position);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(accounts.text_one);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.about)).setText(accounts.text_two);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).setText(accounts.text_three);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите **"передать объект класса в одно легкое движение, а не каждое поле передавать"**.
Тут вам поможет интерфейс `Serializable`

**№1**
ваш класс Accounts должен иметь этот интерфейс

```
   Accounts implements Serializable
```

**№2**
классическое ключ-значение в `putExtra`

```
about.putExtra("myAcc", oneAccount);
```

**№3**
а забираем данные уже чуть-чуть по другому

```
Accounts i = getIntent().getExtras().getSerializableExtra("myAcc");
```

так же можно наследовать класс от `Parcelable`, но там надо еще переписывать методы.

p.s. возможны ошибки, писал от руки.

Comment: не помогло и еще ошибка при вводе getSerializableExtra() -> функции нет

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.psnaccounts.Accounts
        at com.example.psnaccounts.AboutActivity.onCreate(AboutActivity.java:34)              Accounts packname = (Accounts) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("packname");